# SSIS package with logging enabled using an "ssis log provider for text files" writes thousands of null characters

Tags: logging, ssis, text-files

I have an SSIS package set up with logging that writes to a text file.  This works fine except for the fact that it logs thousands and thousands of NUL characters to the file each time the package runs.

Any idea why this is happening and what can be done to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like one or more settings in the SSIS logging tasks it not set correctly.

Under SSIS > Logging, you probably have a task under the container Package selected that is returning NULL.  Check all of the boxes under Package.  Then select the Details tab and verfiythat all of the correct Events are selected.  One of those may also be returning null each time it takes place.

I recommend unchecking some of the options and running the package to see if this changes your log results.  I also apply text log files and have had similar issues in the past that were resolved by this approach.